# Xamarin.Forms Android App Can't connect to internet

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a boiler plate Xamarin.Forms Cross Platform app.  I don't know what the settings are to allow the ANDROID App to connect to the internet.  In UWP I had to enable some capabilities and now it works. In Android Manifest I Enabled  "Internet" but still no luck Not sure whats missing.

```
      public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        CurrentRaceInfo cur_race = new CurrentRaceInfo();
        try
        {
            var cur_racedetail = await client.GetStringAsync("Place URL here");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var ooo = e;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

> ```
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection timed out
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b6] in :0 
>   at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0016d] in :0 
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00058] in :0 
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in :0 
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__63.MoveNext () [0x00450] in :0 
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__63.MoveNext () [0x004ab] in :0 
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in :0 
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+d__54.MoveNext () [0x0007d] in :0 
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
>   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in :0 
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0004b] in :0 
>   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at NInterpret.Interpreter.callAMethod (NInterpret.AMethod m, NInterpret.AType[] ptypes, NInterpret.AType[] genericMethodArgs, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] genericArgsIndex, System.Object[] args, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] byRefArgs, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] byRefTarget, System.Object target, System.Boolean virtualCall) [0x0049b] in :0 
>   at NInterpret.Interpreter.callMethodReference (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] gargs, Mono.Cecil.MethodReference ms, System.Boolean virtualCall) [0x00384] in :0 
>   at NInterpret.Interpreter.interpretBlock (System.Object[] args, System.Object[] locals, Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction initialInstruction, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpSet`1[T] inTries, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] lastException) [0x00fb7] in :0 
>   at NInterpret.Interpreter.interpretBlock (System.Object[] args, System.Object[] locals, Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction initialInstruction, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpSet`1[T] inTries, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] lastException) [0x0013c] in :0 }
> ```

I can Create the error by creating using VS 2017 File > New Project> Web >Cross Platform> Mobile App(Xamarin.Forms) > I select Blank Project, Put check boxes in IOS, ANdroid and UWP.  Select .Net Standard as Code sharing strategy.  press Ok.  After prject is set up I Set Android as Start up project, Place the code above in the Shared Project MainPage.Xaml.cs  For emulator I am using Xamarin Live player to connect to my Phone  its an Android API 24.  I Set some breakpoints and run the project.   It then throws the error below on the  Client.GetStringAsync() call.  As stated earlier I had simliar issue with UWP but all I had to do was enable some capibilities and the issues went away, I'm sure I will have similar issue on IOS but just tackling 1 issue at a time for now.

Comment: have you verified that you can connect using Chrome on the device/emulator?

Comment: I am using my phone to build the app. My phone does connect to the internet and works on everything else.

Comment: I good test for anyone would be to Set up a new Cross platform Xamarin Forms app with VS and set Android as start project and then write some code that reads a WebAPI. I'm using VS Studio Ent. 2017 v 15.6.4

Comment: and, are you trying to connect to the internet or some local server?

Comment: Trying to connect to the Internet.  Reads data from a WebAPI Off site

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168599/discussion-between-joe-ricklefs-and-jason).

Comment: Added Exception to Original Post

Comment: Can you give me a demo, I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Updated Explanation/  Would love to demo but not sure how. But This error appears on every PC that I attempt to run it on. All have similar environments.

Comment: Hi, it works on my phone, and I get the return json:11111111111111111{"marcoIsland":null,"raceName":"O’Reilly Auto Parts 500","trackName":"Texas Motor Speedway","lastUpdated":"2013-02-21T20:11:24.427","lapsCompleted":334,"lapsTotal":334,"lapsToGo":0,"flagState":"checkered"}， here is my [demo](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/NetWorkPCL)

Comment: Just pulled you build and I get the same error I get on mine. I'm starting to believe that its enviromntal, but I have installed VS on 2 diff PCs, and I can reproduce the error.

Comment: I will Share my PC with you to figure this out.   I've spent probably 60 hours on this and its crazy that it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, it works on my computer. I have VPN on my computer, if I turn on the VPN, the project will not work, it give me the "System.Net.WebException Error: NameResolutionFailure", not your exception, if I turn off the VPN, it will work. So I suggest you open the url in your Phone's Chrome to test it firstly. I also have spend about 8 hours to reproduce your question, I try to use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to Intercept the network request. Mybe you can use it to test the http request.

Comment: Please leave me the comments with "@", or I can't see your message immediately.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Its a network issue....   Just dawned on me last night and then I red you msg this morning.  I will confirm today by testing in a different network.  but I susupect this server is on premise, and all the PCs have had their Host files modified to account for that.  However the Android Emulator or my Phone don't utilize the Host files... I can't believe I didn't think of that till now.  Anyway now I will just need to figure out how to modify the Emulator so that it will work on this network. I will update when I have working.

Comment: Good luck! Can I post an answer for the question?

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Heck yeah.  If you know how to modify the Host File for a Android emulator running if VS that would be great also, but that may be a new Thread:)